# Is there a Subversion host that lets end-users file bug reports/is friendly towards end-users?

Tags: svn, hosting

Is there a Subversion host that:

- lets end-users file bug reports
- arranges bug reports/customer support as a message board
- is free?

I'm using Unfuddle right now and pretty happy with it, and I'm trying out Fogbugz now, I was just curious as to what my other options are as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoogleCode hosting:

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/GettingStarted#Creating_a_Project

Comment: Sounds good, but is there a way for end-users to sign up to submit issues without my having to approve their accounts first?

Comment: +1, Google was great and ridiculously user-friendly, but i'm still looking for something where the end-users can sign up themselves, without approval.

Answer (score 1):

in the end, i decided to just keep things simple and host SVN on my own server (Dreamhost) and set up a forum for end-users.  it's ugly and unintegrated but i guess it's working for everyone.